# Viewpager with fragments and gridview with viewswitcher

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

How many pager fragments does Android save using `FragmentPagerAdapter`? It seems to me that it saves eight fragments on the left, because they don't load correctly, so it seems that they aren't rebuilding.
Can I change how many fragments to keep?

Answer (score 1):

[FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) doesn't actually do any removal of Fragments, it simply detaches the Fragment (which means it's state is kept, but it's Views are destroyed).

If you want the Fragments to be fully removed, then use [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) instead.

Comment: It does the same using FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Comment: What is the ViewPager's offscreen page limit set to? [setOffscreenPageLimit()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))